# Can I sand bamboo floors?

Tags: floor, hardwood-refinishing, hardwood

I have prefinished bamboo floors in the kitchen and they are not in a good shape. I was wondering if i can sand them. Somebody told me that i can't send prefinished floors (oak or bamboo), somebody else said i can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It seems](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Can_you_refinish_a_bamboo_floor) that you can refinish it, pretty much just like any hardwood floor.  However bamboo has a very low burn temperature, so you need to be careful with the sander that you don't burn it.

Answer (score 5):

It really depends on the floor. Some flooring is *very* thin layers over particle board, so sanding can easily eat through all the top layer. Other flooring is thicker. If you can, see if you can figure out the manufacturer and type. If not, the best thing to do is find a place where experiments will not be visible and try sanding. In a kitchen, one great option is under the fridge or dishwasher. If those are easy to roll out of the way, you can get a sander and give it a shot.